# Elasticsearch ver 1.4.2 polling configuration is not working. why?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, polling

Hi' I am trying to poll table data every 5 sec but it does not work

```
POST /_river/mytest_river/_meta
{
    "type":"jdbc",
    "jdbc": 
    {
        "driver":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
        "url":"jdbc:sqlserver://[my_ip];databaseName=mega",
        "user":"sa","password":"******",
        "sql":"SELECT [OrderID],[CustomerName],[UserFullName],[Status]  FROM [Orders_Table]",
        "poll":"5s",
        "index": "mega",
        "type": "orders_table"     
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `"schedule"` parameter as described here:
[Time scheduled execution of JDBC river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#time-scheduled-execution-of-jdbc-river)

Comment: OK. I add a scheduled but now i see prev versions of query results + the current one.. why?

Comment: Read more here: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc/issues/520 or here http://grokbase.com/t/gg/elasticsearch/1544yst8m6/chunk-wise-incremental-data-feed-into-es-jdbc-feeder-river Basicly you'll have to set it up by yourself. Somehow. Google around.

Comment: Hi, i read some articles but found no answer. why do i receive old records when searching by key?? I should only get 1 . the latest one.

Comment: No you shouldn't, jdbc river isn't that smart and bulk inserts data that your query returns. If your table has 10 records, river will pick 10 records. If you add one record there, it will pick 11. Simple as that. And by the way, use this query `SELECT [OrderID] AS [_id], [OrderID],[CustomerName],[UserFullName],[Status] FROM [Orders_Table]`. I'd strongly suggest reading documentation before asking questions. This has really been answered many times.

Comment: no. this is not the issue.. the issue is that the elastic query on the id returns same row in several versions of it..(for each update of the row in the DB)

Comment: If you will specify _id field, it will overwrite elasticsearch document with that ID.